# Provisioning Script using CustomScriptExtension on Windows2019 Fails

Tags: azure, docker, powershell, terraform

I'm trying to wrap my brain around an issue with either the TF Code, or me. I've got a VM Set that I'm mapping over, and on each one, I have a CustomScriptExtension that *should* install Docker on the VMs.

When I run the plan, it builds the VMs, and the Custom Script runs, however when I RDP into the machine, and attempt a `docker info` It's telling me that docker isn't installed.

A quick cursory glance of C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.*\Downloads\ Shows that the installer script is indeed being downloaded, but it doesn't seem to be installing.

Here's the AzureRM Resource (Sanitized):

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "bootstrap-scripts" {
  for_each = local.XXXXXX

  name = "${each.key}-bootstrap"
  virtual_machine_id = module.XXXXXXXX[each.key].virtual_machine_id
  publisher = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.10"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
  
  {
    "commandToExecute" : "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File install-docker-ce.ps1",
    "fileUris" : ["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/Windows-Containers/Main/helpful_tools/Install-DockerCE/install-docker-ce.ps1"]
  }
  SETTINGS
    
  }
```

And the output from the log at C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension

```
[
    {
        "version":"1",
        "timestampUTC":"2022-10-21T20:03:44.6989395Z",
        "status":{"name":"powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File install-docker-ce.ps1",
        "operation":"Command Execution Finished",
        "status":"success",
        "code":0,
        "formattedMessage":{
        "lang":"en-US",
        "message":"Command execution finished"
        },
        "substatus":[
            {
                "name":"StdOut",
                "status":"success",
                "code":0,"formattedMessage":{
                    "lang":"en-US",
                    "message":"Querying status of Windows feature: Containers...\r\nEnabling feature Containers...\r\nWARNING: You must restart this server to finish the installation process.\r\nRestart is required; restarting now...\r\nCreating scheduled task action (C:\\Packages\\Plugins\\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\\1.10.12\\Downloads\\0\\install-docker-ce.ps1 )...\r\nCreating scheduled task trigger...\r\nRegistering script to re-run at next user logon...\r\n"
                }
            },
            {
                "name":"StdErr",
                "status":"success",
                "code":0,
                "formattedMessage":{
                    "lang":"en-US",
                    "message":"Register-ScheduledTask : No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.\r\n(12,8):UserId:\r\nAt C:\\Packages\\Plugins\\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\\1.10.12\\Downloads\\0\\install-docker-ce.ps1:150 char:5\r\n+     Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $global:BootstrapTask -Action $a ...\r\n+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (PS_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/...S_ScheduledTask) [Register-ScheduledTa \r\n   sk], CimException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070534,Register-ScheduledTask\r\n \r\n"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

from what I'm reading, it seems to set up the scheduled task to reboot the server, but it looks like it never does? However even after a manual restart, it's still not installed.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I cannot use anything out of the Azure Public Marketplace, in case someone wanted to mention using a premade image. I am relegated to using images that are stored in our private collection

Comment: Have you taken a look at `StdErr` error code? Your PowerShell script should fail with non-exit code 0 when it fails to run something. Looks like that's not something that is happening in your case.

Comment: Yea, I think that what is going on, is that it can't run the script under any user account, since it's being provisioned DURING the TF apply process. I think if I invoke the script with the azurerm vm extension using the Powershell Start-Process, that might work. Sorry it took so long to reply, I got handed a more urgent task that I needed to handle first.